# Double the size of the div to make pattern background-image work properly

Tags: background-image

I have a div element with a background-image. The image is a pattern which cannot be cut, so it always has to end to the bottom of the image. The image height is 400px. So I want the div to always be 400px, or higher, but it has to be divided by 400px so that the background image doesn't cut away when there will be text overflow. Example: 400px->800px->1200px etc.

Comment: Can´t you wrap all those divs inside a bigger one and set the background pattern to that one?

Answer (score 0):

if the content ain't changed after the page load u can use a simple javascript:

```
    window.onload = function(){
        var divs = document.getElementsByClass('exampleClass');
        for(var i=0;i<divs.length ; i++)
            if(divs[i].clientWidth % 400 != 0)
                divs[i].clientWidth += 400 - (divs[i].clientWidth % 400);

    }
```

Comment: Forgot to mention what it does:

The if-statement checks if the current width is not a 400 multiplier(?) (-400,0,400,800,1200). If it ain't, the width is increased to 400-<how much too tall it is>.

Example:
the width is 500:
it is not a 400 multiplier:
    it's 100 too long
    then we get 500+(400-100)=800
TADA!

Comment: Noticed two new things: 1: clientWidth is not mutable, to set the new width you have to use divs[i].setAttribute("style", "width:"+(divs[i].clientWidth + 400 - (divs[i].clientWidth % 400)) + "px;"); 2: I keep speaking of width when you said height, just change width to height everywhere